# How does the existence of Himyarite Kingdom (a Jewish state that formed after the exile) impact the formation of a future Jewish messianic state?

Tags: halacha, history, israel

According to the Wikipedia page on this topic, since the reign of Abikarib Asʿad (c. 384-433 CE), Judaism was adopted as the de facto state religion of the Himyarite Kingdom. It seems  that Judaism may have been adopted to some extent as much as two centuries earlier, but inscriptions to polytheistic deities ceased after this date. It was embraced initially by the upper classes, and possibly a large proportion of the general population over time. Virtually all scholars are in agreement about this except one, who still acknowledges that it definitely makes sense for it to be this way though and even he acknowledges that by the time of Dhu Nuwas's reign (c. 517 - 527 CE) there is basically zero disagreement among the scholars that the king was Jewish, there was presence of Jewish tribal influence and other Jewish influence among the elites as well as the population most likely, the ruling elites and nobles were Jewish, etc.

Taking into account that a Jewish state existed after the exile, how does this impact Jewish beliefs in the sense of, does it deter or delay the arrival of the Messiah? Did they break the Jewish law regarding Jews not being allowed to have a state until the arrival of the Messiah? Does this state existing in the past have any impact on the future of Jews or does it change the laws?

I'm not sure if I phrased this well, but please let me know if I need to clarify since AFAIK Jews aren't allowed to have a state until the arrival of the Messiah, but a Jewish state has apparently existed long before even the contemporary "State of Israel". So how does this work Halachically and what happens now?

Comment: Why aren't Jews allowed to have a state before the time of Messiah? cf. The Bar Kokhba autonomy, purportedly medieval Kuzar and of course the State of Israel.

Comment: Hm, perhaps I was wrong. I think that the B.Talmud, Tractate Kesubos, 111a is rather about forceful recapture of the Land of Israel, but not about establishing a Jewish state somewhere else per se. Also the theme of collecting all the Jews to the Land of Israel, etc. is different from establishing a Jewish state somewhere else. I do remember hearing some Rabbis still saying that one cannot even have any Jewish state though, but unfortunately I can't remember who it was. Thanks for bringing my attention to this, I'm new to Jewish beliefs and always looking to learn more.

Comment: The problem is having a state in Israel proper. There is no problem with a different kingdom being Jewish, as long as they don't claim to be the state of the Messiah.

Comment: @Harel13 The state of Israel is very controversial. A large part of the Chassidic and more right-wing Litvish world were against it for those reasons.

Comment: @N.T. this is not the place for an in-depth debate on the matter, but I will point out that in the first couple of Zionist Congresses there were many representatives of what we would today call "Charedi" or "Ultra-Orthodox" Jews, fully aware that they were working together with "secular"/"haskalic", etc Jews towards bringing about a Jewish State in Eretz Yisrael.

Comment: The split occurred when the "Charedi" Jews realized that the "secular" Jews were not interested in the state having a religious Torah-based public sphere. The 3 Vows was a later attempt at rationalizing the move. As I said, this is not the place for a proper debate, so I won't say anything further for now.

Comment: @setszu I forgot to welcome you to the site. Welcome, and I hope you stick around. Yes, the 3 Vows of Ketubot are only relevant for the Land of Israel. Where there are rumors, legends and stories of Jewish countries abroad, there is never any debate on their legitimacy from Jewish legal sources.

Comment: @Harel13 Thanks Harel! So if I understand this correctly, Jews are perfectly allowed to have a state for themselves as long as it's not on the Land of Israel (and there isn't really a debate about this right?)? If such a state where to be established, what laws would it follow? Do you know if there are any special Halachic laws in such a case regarding what they can and cannot do and how to distinguish itself from the Messianic Jewish state in Israel (or please just let me know where I can read more about this)? Thanks again for your clarification on this topic.

Comment: I did not say that they aren't allowed in the Land of Israel. What I'm saying is that there isn't any problem for such a country to be outside of the Land of Israel. As a country outside of the Land of Israel, it's subject to pretty much all laws of non-Israel countries, which means that commandments that are only relevant to Israel cannot be observed elsewhere. That's pretty much what distinguishes it from Israel: Location and laws pertaining to extra-Israel countries.

Comment: @Harel13 I didn't say all chareidi; I said some. I believe those like the Satmar Rav and Brisker Rav were against it from the beginning.

Comment: @Harel13 Thank you for your reply. Just one last thing - say I'm a ruler of a kingdom and my kingdom becomes Jewish along with me and the elites, etc. and some good chunk of the populace. Am I allowed to make my own laws and implement ideologies/philosophies similar to say Confucianism at state-level as long as they don't interfere with the Halacha? And would Talmudic laws and Halacha in general become also the law of the country?

Comment: I would imagine yes, but I don't really know. You could ask that as a separate question.